# SSAS deployment error : user does not have permission to create a new object

Tags: ssas, sql-server-data-tools, cube, ssdt-bi, ssdt-2017

I recently when I want to deploy my `SSAS` project to server, faced this error:

> Either the domain\user user does not have permission to create a new object in `database`, or the object does not exist.

[image]

I searched on the internet and do some solutions but none worked. I do these steps and it solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Login to `SSAS` instance on the server.

2)In `Role` node you should see (at least) one role:

[image]

3)In the `SSDT` in role node in solution explorer define a new role with exactly same role name in `SSAS` server instance and check all check boxes:

[image]

[image]

4)In `Membership` tab add active directory users:

[image]

Now you can deploy your project without above error!